# How can I flash with User-debug builds to Pixel device?

Tags: android, android-build

How can I flash my Pixel 2 XL device with User-debug build for Android Q version?

Is there any information with step by step procedure or any documented information or video links? I tried to googling and couldn't get to it. Since I am new to this topic I don't know how to start.

Checked [this link](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#build-variants) but don't know how to proceed on the information given.